# Writing to a file inside an apply function

Tags: r

For memory reasons, I do not want to save the output of an apply function to a file, but I would like to write the results to a file while the apply loop is running.

I've made the following working example:

```
checkfun <- function(TheArray, fileConn){
    write(as.character(TheArray[1]), fileConn)
}
set.seed(1)
random_data <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=10, data=runif(100))
outfile <- file("checkout.txt")
apply(random_data, 2, checkfun, fileConn=outfile)
close(outfile)
```

Reading the file `checkout.txt` will only contain the value (`0.239629415096715`) of the last column of the `random_data` matrix. Whereas I want it to save the full first row of that matrix in the `checkout.txt` file.
Note that this is an example of the problem I'm facing, saving a row in a matrix is easy enough, I want to write to a file inside the apply function.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Just to be sure, the function in my original apply loop takes relatively long to finish, so I don't think writing to the file will produce too much overhead, even though it would produce quite some overhead in the function here.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a working, minimal, and reproducible sample of your problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, The example of my problem is a minimal working example that reproduces my problem, if you run the code in an R  interpreter. I used R version 3.2.2, if you're interested.
However, I'm unsure that you understand the question I'm asking, in part based on and answer provided previously, but now deleted.
user danielson provided an answer and understood the question and answered it, so I don't think I need to change the phrasing of my question.

Comment: Try `TheArray[1, ]`. For matrices, you need to explicitly define rows/columns. This behavior is different for data.frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change 1 line of your code to open the file for writing in text mode:

```
outfile <- file("checkout.txt", "w")
```